# Display message based on progress bar status in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I created a custom directory for progress bar for form validations.

First progress status is 0%, progress bar below will show '0% completed' message.

Once form is valid then progress bar values will increase from 0% to 50%, and message will show '50% completed' before submitting form.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
    <p progressbar prog="form1.$valid ? '50':'0'" ></p>
    <p  ng-show= "form1.$valid ? '50% is completed':'0% is complted'">

    </p>
    <form name="form1" novalidate>
        <p>
            <span style="color:blue">1) select One</span><br/>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="A" ng-required="true"/>A
            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="B" ng-required="true"/>B
            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q1" name="grp1" value="C" ng-required="true"/>C
        </p>
        <p>
            <span style="color:blue">2) select two</span><br/>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="A" ng-required="true"/>A
            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="B" ng-required="true"/>B
            <input type="radio" ng-model="user.q2" name="grp2" value="C" ng-required="true"/>C
        </p>
        <button class="st" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid"> submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
.directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'progress': '=prog'
        },
        template: '<div class="stripe" style="background-color: #211; height:40px; width:100%;"> <div  ng-style="style" style="background-color:#c11; height:100%"></div> </div>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {       
         $scope.$watch(function() {
                $scope.style = {"width": $scope.progress + "%"}
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Various readability & formatting improvements.

Comment: what's the issue ?